# How to generate a range of nonweekend dates using tools available in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, unix-timestamp

I want to generate a list of files where the name consists of `${filename}.${date}`, for example `file.20111101`, `file.20120703`, starting `November 1, 2011` until today and it should exclude weekends.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this for 2011

```
for y in 2011; do
  for m in {1..12}; do
    for d in  `cal -m $m $y|tail -n +3|cut -c 1-15`; do
      printf "file.%04d%02d%02d\n" $y $m $d;
    done;
  done;
done
```

or this for NOV-2011 to DEC-2013

```
for ym in {2011' '{11,12},{2012..2013}' '{1..12}}; do
  read y m <<<$ym;
  for d in  `cal -m $m $y|tail -n +3|cut -c 1-15`; do
    printf "file.%04d%02d%02d\n" $y $m $d;
  done;
done
```

or until end of this month "hard"

```
for ym in {2011' '{11,12},2012' '{1..7}};do
  read y m <<<$ym;
  for d in  `cal -m $m $y|tail -n +3|cut -c 1-15`;do
    printf "file.%04d%02d%02d\n" $y $m $d;
  done;
done
```

Comment: excuse my reformatting... but I think it improves readability and eases understanding of your nice suggestion. (Note, that for my version of `cal` (on Mac OS X) I do get a few error messages to stdout, which also cause the list of printed filenames to include multiple instances of (invalidly named) `file.20131200`, `file.20131100`,... as well as multiple copies of valid names.)

Comment: are you using bash and does brace expansion work: replace inner for by echo $m $y, also look at man cal -m option, it must display monday in first else it's sunday and cut parameters should be change to -c 4-18

Comment: Yes, I'm using bash. Brace expansion also works. Replacing inner for by `echo $m $y` I already did before your comment (and it shows the same error messages in between valid output, and also shows multiple copies of valid names). My `cal` supports `-m` according to man page.  -- Yes, you are right that my `cal` shows sunday as first day.

Comment: Oh, contrary to what the OSX manpage says, the `cal -m 7 2012` doesn't display a single month, but the complete year. That explains my results.  ;-(

Comment: Option `-1` is not supported by Mac OS X's `cal`. I couldn't find a GNU cal in MacPorts either...

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU date,sed and Bash):

```
seq 0 $((($(date +%s)-$(date -d 20111101 +%s))/86400)) |
sed '5~7d;6~7d' |
xargs -l1 -I '{}' date -d '+{} days 20111101' +file.%Y%m%d
```

Explanation:

- `seq` provides a sequence of days from `20111101` to `today`
- `sed` filters out the weekends
- `xargs` feeds day parameters for the `date` command.

Comment: using date, this may work too : for d in {20111101..$(date +%Y%m%d)};do [[ "$d" =~ ^\d\d\d\d[0-1]\d[0-3]\d$ ]] && [[ "$(date -d $d +%a 2>/dev/null)" =~ ^[MTWF]..$ ]] && date -d $d +%Y%m%d; done

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `dateseq` from `dateutils` (http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/#dateseq).

```
$ dateseq 2017-03-25 $(date +%F) --skip sat,sun -ffile.%Y%m%d
file.20170327
file.20170328
file.20170329
file.20170330
file.20170331
file.20170403
file.20170404
file.20170405
file.20170406
file.20170407
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with gawk:

```
gawk -v START_DATE="2011 11 01 0 0 0" -v FILE="file" '
  BEGIN {

    END_DATE   = strftime( "%Y %m %d 0 0 0", systime() )

    while ( START_DATE <= END_DATE ) {
      split( START_DATE, DATE )
      if ( strftime( "%u", mktime( START_DATE ) ) < 6 ) print FILE "." DATE[ 1 ] DATE[ 2 ] DATE[ 3 ]
      START_DATE = strftime( "%Y %m %d 0 0 0", mktime( DATE[ 1 ] " " DATE[ 2 ] " " ( DATE[ 3 ]+1 ) " 0 0 0" ) )
    }

  }
'
```

This uses a nice property of *mktime* that automatically find the correct date when you increment one of the date components (e.g. "2012-02-33" becomes "2012-03-04").