# How to generate a list of all dates in a range using the tools available in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to download a bunch of files named with ISO-8601 dates. Is there a simple way to do this using bash+GNU coreutils? (Or some trick to make wget/curl to generate the list automatically, but I find that unlikely)

Similar to this question, but not restricted to weekdays: [How to generate a range of nonweekend dates using tools available in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314070/how-to-generate-a-range-of-nonweekend-dates-using-tools-available-in-bash).
I guess that there is a simpler way to do it without that restriction.

Also related to [How to generate date range for random data on bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107506/how-to-generate-date-range-for-random-data-on-bash), but not restricted to a single year.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you have GNU `date`, you could do use either a `for` loop [in any POSIX-compliant shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04):

```
# with "for"
for i in {1..5}; do 
    # ISO 8601 (e.g. 2020-02-20) using -I
    date -I -d "2014-06-28 +$i days"

    # custom format using +
    date +%Y/%m/%d -d "2014-06-28 +$i days"
done
```

or an `until` loop, this time using Bash's extended test `[[`:

```
# with "until"
d="2014-06-29"
until [[ $d > 2014-07-03 ]]; do 
    echo "$d"
    d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
done
```

Note that non-ancient versions of `sh` will also do lexicographical comparison if you change the condition to `[ "$d" \> 2014-07-03 ]`.

Output from either of those loops:

```
2014-06-29
2014-06-30
2014-07-01
2014-07-02
2014-07-03
```

For a more portable way to do the same thing, you could use a Perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;    
use File::Fetch;

my ($t, $end) = map { Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%Y-%m-%d") } @ARGV; 

while ($t <= $end) {
    my $url = "http://www.example.com/" . $t->strftime("%F") . ".log";
    my $ff = File::Fetch->new( uri => $url );
    my $where = $ff->fetch( to => '.' );  # download to current directory
    $t += ONE_DAY;
}
```

Time::Piece, Time::Seconds and File::Fetch are all core modules. Use it like `perl wget.pl 2014-06-29 2014-07-03`.

Comment: The first one can be combined with http://stackoverflow.com/a/8903280/939108 to use an explicit date. But I guess the second option is better then.

Comment: If you want a format other than ISO-8601, you can do  `date -d  $d +"%m/%d/"` or whatever formatting string strikes your fancy instead of the `echo $d` line above.

Comment: The `until` loop is better for "days in a month".

Answer (score 28):

Using GNU date and bash:

```
start=2014-12-29
end=2015-01-03
while ! [[ $start > $end ]]; do
    echo $start
    start=$(date -d "$start + 1 day" +%F)
done
```

```
2014-12-29
2014-12-30
2014-12-31
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
```

Comment: Why not put the test in the while clause? `while [[ $start -le $end ]]; do`

Comment: I mean `while [[ ! $start > $end ]]; do`. The previous one doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

If you are on macOS, then `date` works a bit differently from GNU `date`. Here's a variant to Tom Fenech's `date` invocation that supports both GNU and Darwin:

```
if [ $(uname) = 'Darwin' ]; then
    d=$(date -j -v+1d -f %Y-%m-%d $d +%Y-%m-%d)
elif [ $(uname) = 'Linux' ]; then
    d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
fi
```

Comment: Or just `brew install coreutils`, then use `gdate`

Comment: Check the day offset, needs a -v+${i}d for this to work in the @Tom Fenech example.  MacOSX 12 zsh:
```start=2020-01-01; for i in {1..5}; do date -j -v+${i}d -f %Y-%m-%d "$start" +%Y-%m-%d; done
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this handy function to work with log files in the format *yyyymmdd.log.gz*:

```
function datelist { for dt in $(seq -w $1 $2) ; do date -d $dt +'%Y%m%d' 2>/dev/null ; done ; }
```

It accepts dates in the format *yyyymmdd*.

Comment: This can of course be extremely inefficient if you need big date range. It will generate up to 70 useless days per month and 88 useless months per year, which it will feed to `date` which will give an error.

Comment: @mivk: Indeed. Good if you want a couple of years and if you run it on a fat machine. I haven't given it a second thought since I posted it. In my work, back then, I queried the SQL server, which can return a list of dates and does not need checking. But not everybody has an SQL server running and not all servers are as fast as the corporate one I used.

Answer (score -2):

Since I didn’t know the exact date range, only that the last file was today, I ended up using this variation of the top answer, which starts at today’s date and iterates backwards one day at a time until a download fails (presumably with a 404):

```
d=$(date -I);
while wget "http://www.example.com/$d.log"; do
    d=$(date -I -d "$d - 1 day");
done
```

Comment: Just fyi, people don't like when you answer your own question with a quick n dirty solution when some research might give you a more refined approach

Comment: @pythonian29033 that’s the solution I used *after* reading the top answer though, since this was a slight AB problem. i didn’t know the exact date range, so fetching until 404 was the best for me