# bash loop to extract data from Teradata

Tags: bash, loops

I need to extract data from Teradata into csv files using a tool named `giraffez`. I have to do this one date at a time due to file size constraints. I can do this using the command:

```
giraffez export "sel * from container.table where date='2015-01-01'" table20150101.csv -d ','
```

However, I to put the above code into a loop that will iterate over each day from 2015-01-01 through 2017-06-01. How can I do this?

Comment: Related question (generating a sequence of dates): https://stackoverflow.com/q/25701265/2088135

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop to generate all dates between to dates

```
d='2015-01-01'
while [[ $d < '2017-06-01' ]]; do
    echo "$d"
    d=$(date -d "$d +1 day" "+%Y-%m-%d")
done
```