# Finding All Dates Between Two Dates in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to get all the dates that fall between a start and end date.
This is what I did

```
start="2022-03-02"
end="2022-03-07"
while [[ $start < $end ]] 
  do 
     echo "$start"
     start=$(date -d "$start + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d") 
done
```

This results in an error

```
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

What is it I am missing?

Comment: I've tried it and it works in my environment. Output: ``2022-03-02
2022-03-03
2022-03-04
2022-03-05
2022-03-06
``

Comment: the code works for me; the issue is likely with your version of `date`; what does `date --version` report?

Comment: offtopic: I would rename `start` to something like `loopdate`. Most people will expect a start value to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61324543/1204326)

You can try this if you using on MacOs

```
date -j -v+1d -f %Y-%m-%d $start +%Y-%m-%d
```